# How Do I loop through this Nested Array without having Runtime Exceeded 30seconds Error

Tags: php, arrays, runtime-error

Please am having problem looping through nested array...

I have a $motherarr with 45contents inside it, and each of the content ($childarr) is another array with not less than 11 arrays inside it... And for every item of $childarr is also an array of 9items

When looping through them, I encounter a kind of error indicating that runtime has exceeded 30seconds... But if I reduce the contents of $motherarr to 10 or lesser it works fine...

Please how do I loop through this Arr without these error... Here is my code

```
foreach($motherarr as $childarr => $value) {
//childarr is an array with not less than 11 arrays in each
if(is_array($childarr)) {
    foreach($childart as $key => $val) {
        //$key is an array with 9items in all
        foreach($key as $subkey => $subval){
            //get all the 9 items in $key 
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is this all your code? Is the `//` part in the inner loop expensive? It definitely shouldn't take 30 seconds to look at 11 * 45 = 495 items. I don't see any way to speed up this code otherwise.

Comment: My bad // is just a comment area showing that some works are done their... 

I forgot to add this, Each content of childarr is also an array with 9 items inside it

Comment: That's still only 4455 iterations, should be a blink of an eye unless `//` is expensive work.

Comment: Ok, assuming am having that runtime exceeded error during loop how do I resolve it

Comment: It looks like the loop is not the issue here. But, the task performed inside the loop which is causing the error, as that task is taking too long. So, you need to identify how you can optimize the time for the task inside the loop or maybe find duplicate sub-tasks and move them outside loop if they are not dependent on the value of loop.

Comment: Try tweaking [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php)